# PHP Error is sending the html headers

Tags: php, http-headers

In one of my scripts, something failed and an error was outputted, When i tried to redirect using `header('Location: back.php')`, apparently the headers were already sent.

Now, how is that possible? I don't have a single HTML tag on that page, and I didn't modify the headers in any way.

I found only one thing that could explain this, PHP errors sometimes have HTML tags inside (bold, anchor, etc..) So can this be the cause of that "headers already sent error"? If so, how do i fix it?

Comment: sometimes it can be as simple as a space after a closing `?>` tag.

Comment: by default errors many errors in php will output to the browser, which would cause the headers already sent thing, (well, actually it wouldn't because your code would stop before it even reaches there) but you should fix or handle the errors anyway

Comment: you might try deleting the closing ?> tag, assuming you don't have anything after it such as HTML -- and if you do, that's the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, that answer apparently applies to my problem also.